# Sort Student list based on their teacher id

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparator

I have a list of students with their teacher id to whom they contacted. below is student bean.

```
public class Student {
    private Integer Id;
    private String Name;
    private Integer teacherId;

public Student(Integer empId, String empName, Integer teacherId) {
    super();
    this.empId = empId;
    this.empName = empName;
    this.teacherId = teacherId;
}
   // setters getters
}
```

Now in my main class i have list of students with data like below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     int teacherId = 6;
    List<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();

    list.add(new Student(1002, "Kausik",4));
    list.add(new Student(1004, "Tridibendu",6));
    list.add(new Student(1007, "Ram",8));
    list.add(new Student(1003, "Neeraj",6));
    list.add(new Student(1009, "Manish",8));
    list.add(new Student(1001, "Shyam",1));

    // Sorting collection in ascending order based on teacher id
    Collections.sort(list, new StudentComparator());

}
```

below is my student comparator class. Can any one please help me what do i write in my compare method so that if i pass 2 as teacher id , list should be sorted in as a way that all students contacted to teacher id 2 should be on top and rest must be at bottom.

Or is there any other way i can do this in java?

```
public class StudentComparator implements Comparator<Student> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {        
        return o1.getTeacherId().compareTo(o2.getTeacherId());
    }
}
```

Below is the output what i am getting.

```
Id: 1001, Name: Shyam, TeacherId: 1
Id: 1002, Name: Kausik, TeacherId: 4
Id: 1004, Name: Tridibendu, TeacherId: 6
Id: 1003, Name: Neeraj, TeacherId: 6
Id: 1007, Name: Ram, TeacherId: 8
Id: 1009, Name: Manish, TeacherId: 8
```

but i want output based on passed teacher id as parameter.Mean if i pass 6 as teacher id then my output should be below :

```
Id: 1004, Name: Tridibendu, TeacherId: 6
 Id: 1003, Name: Neeraj, TeacherId: 6
 Id: 1001, Name: Shyam, TeacherId: 1
 Id: 1002, Name: Kausik, TeacherId: 4
 Id: 1007, Name: Ram, TeacherId: 8
 Id: 1009, Name: Manish, TeacherId: 8
```

so teacher have id as 6 should be on top of list.

Comment: what is the problem ..The code seems fine !
What do you mean by `what do i write in my compare method` ?
Did you try printing the `Student object` in your list? Those should be sorted on base of `teacherId ` after using the following code:

`Collections.sort(list, new StudentComparator());`

Comment: i mean sorting based on teacher id passed as parameter. If i say sort by teacher id 6 then below should be output. students contacted to teach 6 should be on top 
Id: 1001, Name: Shyam, TeacherId: 6
Id: 1002, Name: Kausik, TeacherId: 6
Id: 1004, Name: Tridibendu, TeacherId: 5
Id: 1003, Name: Neeraj, TeacherId: 7
Id: 1007, Name: Ram, TeacherId: 8
Id: 1009, Name: Manish, TeacherId: 8

Comment: How would you sort the rest of the students? Or should they be random. So you have students with connected to the TeacherID of 6 on top, where do the rest come? Should 5 or 7 be next, should we do descending, or should it not matter? Need to be a little more specific. Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Also, you wouldn't be overriding the `compare` method as you are adding a new parameter, TeacherID. This may cause issues if you are assuming the compare will be used in other generic functions. If you call it manually, it will work, but only in that way

Comment: @Draken yes teacher id 6 should be on top if i pass 6 as parameter to sorting., rest as come in any order. yes 5 or 7 be next.

Comment: how do i say in code that please sort list by teacher id 6 or 7 etc ?

Comment: You might want to fix your constructor, it refers to fields that does not existing in the current implementation of your class. For ex. this.empId and this.empName

Comment: You can cut your elements with id you needed from list, sort list, and then add elements to the beginning of the list

Answer (score 2):

You can force it to return negative for matched teacher, then normally sort for the rest:

```
public class StudentComparator implements Comparator<Student> {
    private int contactedTeacher;
    public StudentComparator(int contactedTeacherId) {
        this.contactedTeacher = contactedTeacherId;
    }
    @Override
    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
        if(this.contactedTeacher == o1.teacherId) {
            return -1; //Force negative
        } else if(this.contactedTeacher == o2.teacherId) {
            return 1; //Force positive
        }

        //If neither of the compared students contacted the teacher, compare normally by teacher ID
        return o1.getTeacherId().compareTo(o2.getTeacherId());
    }
}
```

Then your sort call becomes:

```
Collections.sort(list, new StudentComparator(teacherId));
```

Comment: What happens if both students contact the Teacher? True, it will still sort fine, but I feel T. Claverie's answer is a little more clearer on how the comparison works

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is make `Student` implement `Comparable<Student>`. For that, you can do:

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {

...

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student s) {
        return this.teacherId.compareTo(s.teacherId);
    }
}
```

Related to your other matter, you can just implement another Comparator which would allow you to split your list into two parts, based on a given teacher id.

```
public class StudentComparator implements Comparator<Student> {
    private Integer id;

    public StudentComparator(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
        int id1 = o1.getTeacherId(); // Let the unboxing do its job
        int id2 = o2.getTeacherId();
        if (id1 == id2) return 0;
        if (id1 == this.id) return 1;
        if (id2 == this.id) return -1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

So, whenever you want to partition your list based on one teacher id, you can call `Collections.sort(studentList, new StudentComparator(teacherId))`